# Paraview. How to create an additional vector with {Field 4, Field 5, Field 6}

Tags: csv, vector, paraview

I really try to know: How to create an additional vector (different of position) with {`Field 4, Field 5, Field 6`}? I mean, how can I create a vector from 3 csv file's specific float columns

In order to do that: First I read my csv file. After I applied the filter `TableToPoints` (with Point Data field association) and define X,Y,Z point coordinates as {Field 0, Field 1, Field 2}, and finally I tried to apply the Calculator filter
`(Field 4)*iHat+(Field 5)*jHat+(Field 6)*kHat`
 but without success.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output? you don't get any vector or the components are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently all works as I described in question. But the mistake was that data was sorted by a different column. I check it adding header line to csv file and checking the spreadsheet data.